# Checking the proof that if every ideal of $R$ is finitely generated then $R$ is Noetherian.

Tags: ring-theory, solution-verification, ideals, noetherian, finitely-generated

Suppose that every ideal of $R$ is finitely generated, we want to show that $R$ is Noetherian.

Suppose that we have an ascending chain of ideals  $$ \mathcal{A}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{A}_2 \subseteq \mathcal{A}_3\subseteq  \dots $$ in $R,$Then $A = \bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} A_i$ is an ideal in $R$. Also, by our first assumption $A$ is finitely generated, say $A = \langle a_1, \dots , a_n \rangle.$

Now, assuming $a_{j} \in A_{i_{j}}$ for some $A_{i_{j}}$ where $j= 1,2, \dots ,n.$ Let $k = \operatorname{max}(i_1, \dots , i_n).$ Then $$a_1,a_2, \dots ,a_n \in A_{k}$$ because we have an ascending chain of ideals by assumption. And this implies that $$A = \langle a_1, \dots , a_n \rangle \subseteq A_k \subseteq A $$ Then we must have that $A = A_k.$

Thus, for any positive integer $i,$ we have that $$A_{k + i} \subseteq A = A_k \subseteq A_{k +i},$$

Hence, $ A_k = A_{k +i}$ for every positive integer $i,$ i.e. our ascending chain of ideals stabilizes. So, $R$ satisfies the $ACC$ condition and hence it is Noetherian as required.

**Is my proof correct?**

Comment: It is correct. I have two tiny points: (1) Would be nice to say somewhere "let $R$ be a (commutative) *ring*. (2) Would be nice to state which definition of Noetherian ring you are using. (I presume you define a ring to be a Noetherian ring iff it satisfies ACC. Some people, however, define Noetherian rings as those in which all ideals are finitely generated. Some other people first prove that this condition is equivalent to ACC, and *then* define a ring to be Noetherian iff it satisfies any of those (equivalent) conditions.)

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback .... I will take your points into consideration @StinkingBishop